# Set UIFont for a UILabel in UITableViewCell subclass

Tags: uitableview, uifont, layoutsubviews

Is it advisable to set `UIFont` of a `UILabel` in `layoutSubviews`. I am subclassing a `UITableViewCell`. We use `layoutSubview` to adjust the `UIView` frame if required, so I am not sure whether I should go with it.

Also, is there is method like `viewDidLoad`, which will be called only once.

I tired to set the font in `initWithCoder`, but `IBOutlet` of `UILabel` is empty in `initWithCoder`.

I can set the `UILabel` text in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, so connection to this custom `UILabel` is correct.

Note:- The cell is initialized from a `UIViewController` in `UIStoryboard`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only layout your views in `layoutSubviews`.  `UITableViewCell` is a subclass of `UIView`, so you can set up your properties here:

```
- (void) awakeFromNib {
    self.myLabel.text = @"my text";    
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to call [super awakeFromNib], before I edit any properties of UILable like text or font.

Comment: Good question.  You don't need to call super in this case.  You can see some example code here, although some stuff is Mac-specific: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSNibAwaking_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks, url helped me to understand my query. Call to super is not required if the parent class is UIView or NSObject. For others if the parent class does not implement -(void) awakeFromNib, it will throw a exception. To avoid this one can perform a check using instancesRespondToSelector:.